# Cannot source tmux config file in a Dockerfile

Tags: build, dockerfile, config, tmux

I'm building a Docker image where I need tmux, and rather than having to run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` every time I start the container (that way madness lies), I'd like to source the config file at build time. However, this isn't working:

```
ARG PYTORCH="1.6.0"
ARG CUDA="10.1"
ARG CUDNN="7"

FROM pytorch/pytorch:${PYTORCH}-cuda${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y man-db manpages-posix vim screen tmux\
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# configuration for tmux
COPY src/.tmux.conf ~/.tmux.conf
RUN tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

I get the error:

```
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-0/default (No such file or directory)
The command '/bin/sh -c tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What's happening? It doesn't seem to be a `file not found` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no tmux server running (no server at all has been running yet, hence the missing file). The config file will be loaded automatically when you run tmux in the container, so the failing line can be dropped

Also, docker doesn't expand the `~`, so you'll need to provide the absolute path. The resulting Dockerfile should look something like this, assuming you're running as root in the container:

```
ARG PYTORCH="1.6.0"
ARG CUDA="10.1"
ARG CUDNN="7"

FROM pytorch/pytorch:${PYTORCH}-cuda${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y man-db manpages-posix vim screen tmux\
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# configuration for tmux
COPY src/.tmux.conf /root/.tmux.conf
```